# Docker Build Process Stuck

Tags: docker, build

My OS---

```
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
```

My Docker Version--

```
# docker --version
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
```

I'm trying to build a docker image--

```
docker build -t image:tag .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  187.9kB
Step 1/8 : FROM node:8.16.2-alpine3.9
 ---> 9c0651c52baf
Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir -p /app
 ---> Running in 85ecdcc9218c
```

It gets stuck on step 2 with no activity. Here's error log from syslog

```
dockerd[4988]: time="2020-02-20x08:28:27.xxxxxxxxxx" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
systemd[1]: Reloading.
systemd-udevd[5315]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
systemd-udevd[5315]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethaxxxxxx: No such file or directory
systemd-networkd[4063]: vethexxxxxx: Link UP
kernel: [ 2304.024934] docker0: port 1(vethexxxxxx) entered blocking state
kernel: [ 2304.024936] docker0: port 1(vethexxxxxx) entered disabled state
kernel: [ 2304.025182] device vethexxxxxx entered promiscuous mode
systemd-timesyncd[4039]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
systemd-udevd[5317]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
systemd-udevd[5317]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethexxxxxx: No such file or directory
kernel: [ 2304.029095] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethexxxxxx: link is not ready
systemd-timesyncd[4039]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
systemd-timesyncd[4039]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
systemd-timesyncd[4039]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
containerd[4987]: time="2020-02-20x08:31:18.xxxxxxxxxx" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/85ecdcc9218c280e97de4bfd38b0d70d83bb601e58a61a2c58fff52db2c90042/shim.sock" debug=false pid=5326
systemd-timesyncd[4039]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
systemd-timesyncd[4039]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
systemd-timesyncd[4039]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
systemd-networkd[4063]: vethexxxxxx: Gained carrier
systemd-networkd[4063]: docker0: Gained carrier
kernel: [ 2304.285614] eth0: renamed from vetha3b6298
kernel: [ 2304.285866] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethexxxxxx: link becomes ready
kernel: [ 2304.285900] docker0: port 1(vethe0b5233) entered blocking state
kernel: [ 2304.285901] docker0: port 1(vethe0b5233) entered forwarding state
systemd-timesyncd[4039]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
systemd-networkd[4063]: vethe0b5233: Gained IPv6LL
systemd-timesyncd[4039]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
systemd-timesyncd[4039]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

Further if I press ^C to quick build process, it breaks my ssh connection too.

Comment: share your docker file

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with `Dockerfile`. It's just issue with docker. When I run `docker container run hello-world`, it get's stuck displaying this line `For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/`
doesn't retun cli prompt.